# No minimum, but maximum vertical size of scrolled window with viewport

Tags: c, gtk

I use a scrolled window with viewport inside a dialog, it looks like this:

[image: Dialog that includes a scrolled window with viewport]

My question: Is it possible to set this scrolled window that it does not only not exceed a certain vertical size, but also shrinks if text shown inside the scrolled window does not take the whole space of the scrolled window? The first "no exceeding" condition works well by using a simple `gtk_widget_set_size_request`, so I just would like to know whether this could be combined with some sort of "auto shrink".

Code I currently use is

```
GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), label);
gtk_widget_set_size_request (scrolled_window, 570, 125);
```

I usually use also a label with text for this dialog, but since it is not important for this question I've removed the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen right now that even though

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request (scrolled_window, 570, 
(gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (label) < 125) ? 
gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (label) : 125);
```

is not actually an auto shrink in the sense i had asked for, it serves my purpose good enough. So I am going to use this.

Comment: If that works, then great. Note that it can be written slighly better by using glib's [`MIN()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Standard-Macros.html#MIN:CAPS) macro: `gtk_widget_set_size_request (scrolled_window, 570, MIN(gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (label), 125));`.

Comment: Ah yes true, since I use such a dialog two times, this looks indeed better!